# Как в Гугл Таблице настроить автоматическое копирование строки по условию на другой лист и удаление после копирования на исходном листе?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть гугл таблица с задачами сотрудников. Как сделать, что если сотрудник поставил статус задачи "Выполнена", то строка с этой задачей копировалась на другой лист, а на исходном удалялась

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  Logger.log(e.value);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetS = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var sheetD = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var lastColumn = sheetS.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = sheetD.getLastRow();
  if (e.value === 'TRUE') {
    
    var range = e.range;
    var row = range.getRow();
    Logger.log(row);
    var val = sheetS.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();
    sheetD.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn).setValues(val);
    sheetS.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```