# Копирование определенных ячеек строки на другой лист

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Уточнение к [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229669/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB-%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83).Как сделать, что если сотрудник поставил статус задачи "Выполнена", то определенные ячейки строки с этой задачей копировалась на другой лист, чтоб копировалась не вся строка.

Comment: Дубль? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229669/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%93%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb-%d0%a2%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83

Comment: да, но он удален, новый отдельный вопрос

Comment: Где код? Где проект? Или нужно копировать из соседнего топика? В том топике строка не "копируется", а "переносится". Это существенно.

Answer (score 0):

Если топором, то нужно вместо этого

```
var val = sheetS.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();
sheetD.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, lastColumn).setValues(val);
```

вставить это

```
var val = sheetS.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastColumn).getValues();
const values_ = val.filter((_, i) => [0, 2, 7].indexOf(i) !== -1);
sheetD.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, 1, values_[0].length).setValues(values_);
```

`[0, 2, 7]` - индексы колонок, которые нужно оставить.