# перенос строки в гугл таблицах

Tags: google-spreadsheet

ранее на этой форуме был найден вот такой скрипт (ниже в тексте) , который переносит строку на лист2 из листа1, после того как поставить галочку в столбце "А" листа1. У меня же есть таблица  длиной примерно 300-500 строк ( кол-во строк изменяется в зависимости от месяца) и в конце таблицы идет другая таблица которая называется "ОТГРУЖЕННЫЕ ПРОЕКТЫ". Так вот мне нужно в основной таблице в столбце "W" тоже чтобы проставлялись в квадратах галочки в соответствующей строке и чтобы вся строка переносилась в таблицу "ОТГРУЖЕННЫЕ ПРОЕКТЫ" и все это на одном листе.

Код почему то вставить не могу. Прилагаю ссылку [Как в Гугл Таблице настроить автоматическое копирование строки по условию на другой лист и удаление после копирования на исходном листе?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1229669/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB-%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83)

Comment: пример вашей таблицы покажите

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tzkdL8WDa4RZtyNGk-IjXQFlwt3SiGNDiYoH9RUJAOc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Готовое решение https://googlesheets.ru/kak-perenesti-stroku-iz-tablicy-gugl-na-drugoj-list/

Comment: Конечно хорошо НО это все же про перенос строки на ДРУГОЙ лист. Мне же нужно перенести строку в этом же листе просто ниже основной таблицы в определенную область.